# Nestjs Swagger UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `prototype` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, typescript, swagger, nestjs

I am working on a Nestjs REST API project where I have to add swagger. I used this repo as an example: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/11-swagger

but I am getting this error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'prototype' of 'undefined' or 'null'`

and this one:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

the project is here:
https://github.com/strdr4605/nestjs-rest-api/blob/swagger/src/main.ts

Comment: I used your main.ts file in the sample project and it works fine. The problem must be somewhere else, maybe one of your controllers? Also try reinstalling and updating your dependencies, never hurts.

Comment: @KimKern, yes I did a mistake in controllers/services. Not sure but maybe because I was using ObjectID as a type of id in PUT/DELETE methods in controller and services. Changed to string type.

Comment: Good to hear that it is working now. :-) Consider deleting your question or adding an answer (marked as solved) describing what you did to resolve your problem. Also, it's always good to include the relevant parts of the code in your post instead just links to it. Links might stop working in the future.

Comment: i have something similar, with Request and Response of express, i am using the decorator like: method(  @Res() res: Response ) when trying to run this using NestJs Swagger module Response is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config of swagger was OK. Not sure but maybe because I was using ObjectID as a type of id in PUT/DELETE methods in controller and services. Changed to string type and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with Swagger trying to parse payload for Kafka messages inside event controller, so I added `ApiExcludeEndpoint` to exclude message handler

```js
@ApiExcludeEndpoint()
@EventPattern('topic', Transport.KAFKA)
public async handleEvent(@Payload() message: EventDto): Promise<void> {
// ...
```